# Proper place for validation code in a service?

Tags: validation, fluentvalidation, service-layer

I am using `FluentValidation` and a `Service Layer` for my MVC application.

I have a question regarding where you would put logic to check for duplicate items.

Say you have a `CategoryService` and a `CategoryValidator`, would you put the logic to check for a duplicate category name in the service or in the validator using the `Must` predicate?

In either method below, I do common things like checking for a valid category name in the validator.

**Method 1**

```
public bool AddCategory(Category category)
{
    var validationResult = validationService.Validate(category);

    if (!validationResult.IsValid)
        return false;

    categoryRepository.Add(category);

    return true;
}

public CategoryValidator(ICategoryService service)
{
    RuleFor(x => x.Name)
        .NotEmpty()
        .Must((category, name) =>
        {
            return service.GetCategories().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == name) == null;
        });
}
```

**Method 2**

```
public bool AddCategory(Category category)
    {
        var existing = categoryRepository.Query().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == category.Name);

        if (existing != null)
            return false;

        categoryRepository.Add(category);

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in doing the validation in both places. It should be sufficient to do all validation in the validator.